# QT Creator wants me to remove many programs before I can install it via Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, qt, qt-creator, ubuntu-gnome

I've just upgraded my Ubuntu-gnome version from 14.04 to 14.04.02 and somehow I lost my QT Creator software which I commonly use to do my coding.

I decided to install it again. When I tried to install the QT Creator again through Ubuntu Software Center, somehow it asked me to remove many software, such as cheese, empathy, gdm, gir1.2, gnome-contacts, gnome-control-server, gnome-shell, gstreamer1.0, totem, xserver-xorg, and many more.

My Questions
1. Why does this happen?
2. What should I do in order to install the QT Creator without removing those softwares?

Comment: This may be related to the issues with `libcheese` mentioned in [Can't install libglew-dev because libcheese and libclutter don't have the required versions](/q/588695).

Comment: what version did you have of QTCreator? What version are you trying to install? I would guess that it is an incompatabilty with gtk3.

Answer (score 1):

The one of following command lines which one you should install using the terminal:

**14.04:**

```
sudo apt-get install libegl1-mesa-drivers
```

**14.10:**

```
sudo apt-get install libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

It will remove and update some programs automatically. 
Then, you yourself can install QT Creator w/o removing some programs you do not want.

No Sweat!
Vote me if it works

Answer (score 0):

QT Creator needs libglew-dev which is not available for 14.04.2 yet.

What you can do:

1. Downgrade the kernel and use the version for trusty version of kernel and relative drivers.
2. Wait for the upgrade